# How to read multiple NFC cards on iOS with react-native-nfc-manager

Tags: react-native, core-nfc, react-native-nfc-manager

I'm building a react native app using `react-native-nfc-manager`. I need to allow the user to read multiple NFC cards, processing the value returned between each read.  I have no problem doing this on Android, where I call to `.requestTechnology()`, `.getTag()`, `.mifareUltralightHandlerAndroid.mifareUltralightReadPages()` and `.cancelTechnologyRequest()`. I then process the value returned and repeat the process to read the next card, until canceled by the user.

This approach doesn't work on iOS. No matter what I do, the first read succeeds, but the second read fails. Even though I have a 1.5 sec delay before calling `readNfc()` again, and the card is no longer next to the phone, the second call to `getTag()` always immediately returns the first card's data (as shown in a console.log of `nfcTag.id`) and fails on the call to `.sendMifareCommandIOS()`.  No matter what I do, it seems the first card read is somehow still "seen" by `.getTag()` the second time my `readNfc()` is called.

Not shown here, but I've separated the calls to `.requestTechnology()` and `.cancelTechnologyRequest()` so they only get called before the first call and when canceled.

How can loop through reading cards and processing results on iOS *without having to stop the NFC reader and require the user press a button to restart it?*

```
const readNfc = async () => {

let readPages = null;
console.log('[nfcServices] readNfc Starting...');

try {
    // Wait for tag    
    await NfcManager.setAlertMessageIOS('Scan a card…’);
    const nfcTag = await NfcManager.getTag();
    console.log('[nfcServices] readNfc getTag returned ', nfcTag.id);
    
    // Read one four-page array from tag
    readPages = await NfcManager.sendMifareCommandIOS([0x30, 16]);
    await NfcManager.setAlertMessageIOS(‘Card read!');
    console.log('[nfcServices] readNfc readPages: ', readPages);

} catch (ex) {
    // Error
    console.log('[nfcServices] readNfc ERROR: ', ex);
    NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest().catch(() => 0);
} finally {
    console.log('[nfcServices] readNfc returning: ', readPages);
    return(readPages);
}

}
```